# The meaning of simple regular expression

Tags: regex

Can someone help me with these 2 regex:

```
First: "^\\s+|\\s+$"
Second: "\\s{2,}"
```

Comment: Have a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: You can experiment with them at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this or search with google. It's not that complicated to interprete those regular expressions.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html#

For example:

\s matches whitespaces
{2,} means 2 of it or more

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a tool dat can 'document' the expressions? This can help you understand them.

Using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) (Paid however in my opinion the best tool available) the expression is documented as below:

```
// ^\s+|\s+$
// 
// Options: ^ and $ match at line breaks
// 
// Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails) «^\s+»
//    Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
//    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
// Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire match attempt fails if this one fails to match) «\s+$»
//    Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (spaces, tabs, and line breaks) «\s+»
//       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
//    Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```